# Height:100% with CSS too large for screen if another div is present

Tags: css

I read through the other 100% CSS solutions but most of them just don't work for my project unfortunately (such as using position:fixed, etc).

Basically I have a logo and a content window. The logo is 100px in height and 100% in width, and I want the content window to be covering the whole remaining area. I also want it to expand automatically, if the content window exceeds the windows height (e.g. using the min-height property).

Can you point me towards the right way to do this?

My problem is that the content window height always seems to be referencing the original size and not the size of the parent container, hence there will be scrollbars, even when the content is short.

Below my (shortened) code:

**CSS**:

```
html, body
{
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color:#000000;
}

#wrapper
{
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}

#header
{
 height:100px;
}


#content {
 background-color:#eee; 
 min-height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<body> 

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="header"></div>
 <div id="content">
  content..

 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}

.header{
    background:red;
    height:100px;
}

.content{
    background:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rVRFF/

note: .header `height` and .content `top` values must match.

Comment: almost, but unfortunately the blue area doesn't extend when the text in the contents-container exceeds the window area: http://jsfiddle.net/r9JRy/ (scroll down)

Comment: ahh, you mean minimum height is to fill the screen and expand if content exceeds.

Comment: exactly! Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @g_thom: sorry, didn't see your post, but unfortunately it's not what I want, since when there is not enough content, it will not fill the whole window: http://jsfiddle.net/ANFN4/

Comment: ok, I ended up using Josephs solution and added a overflow:auto element to contents, which sorta fixed my problem. Thanks all